# Will Bradford pear suckers produce flowers?

Tags: growth, flowering, suckers

A 21 year old Bradford pear split and was cut back to ground level. After a couple of years there are at least 20 suckers that are 4 foot high making a thick hedge. Will they keep getting taller or remain bush like? Will they flower if left alone? There are no thorns.